# How to get JsonConvert.SerializeObject to wrap objects in { ...}

Tags: c#, json, json.net

After calling JsonConvert.SerializeObject on my class the resulting JSON looks like this :-

```
{
  "commands": [
    {
      "req": "login",
      "password": "1111"
    }
  ]
}
```

However I need it to look like this with the additional { }

```
{
  "commands": [
    {
      "req": "login"
    },
    {
      "password": "1111"
    }
  ]
}
```

Code is being generated using https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp

Both are valid Json but I need the braces as I'm calling a 3rd party API that requires them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you made your classes like this:

```
public class ApiRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("commands")]
    public List<Command> Commands { get; set; }

    public ApiRequest() 
    {
        Commands = new List<Command>();
    }

    public void Add(Command command)
    {
        Commands.Add(command);  
    }
}

public class Command : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    public Command(string key, string value) : base()
    {
        Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

Then you could create your JSON like this:

```
var req = new ApiRequest();
req.Add(new Command("req", "login"));
req.Add(new Command("password", "1111"));

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req, Formatting.Indented);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kJD81u

Comment: The Dictionary is the key, since they are different objects. Good solution!